# Deploy Go+React full stack application on AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: reactjs, go, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am in the process of deploying a full stack web application on AWS.
The app is:

1. Go lang in the backend
2. React for the front end

As I understand, since react builds static files (HTML+CSS+Js), the use-case here is to deploy the go backend in aws elastic beanstalk which uses an EC2 instance to run the web server. The part I cannot understand is where should I deploy the front end? Is this possible with only one elastic beanstalk service?

I have seen a similar example with MERN stack in this [blog post](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/11/18/react-nodejs-on-aws-how-to-deploy-a-mern-stack-app-to-amazon-ec2). Does anybody know if this is possible in my case?

Comment: Put your static assets in S3 and serve them with Cloud front.  Think of the frontend as a separately deployed component of your application.  For that matter, you might consider running your go application in a lambda behind API gateway unless persistence or high request volumes are part of your expectations.  It's a lot cheaper and less hassle in the long run compared to  EC2 instances

Comment: @DanielFarrell Thanks for your reply. As I see from my research, the AWS S3 bucket is common for frontend scenarios. So I will consider placing my React build inside S3. I assume I have to decide between Lambda and Elastic beanstalk for backend.